# 20px is reserved for scrollbar in grid (GXT3)

Tags: gwt, grid, scrollbar, gxt

I have created a GXT3 grid and set its width to certain value.

After first rendering grid is keeping 20px extra at right side, I think it's for vertical scroll bar. As one of column is not fixed,later on it fits to total width.

I tried even decreasing totalwidth of grid, not success though.Because everytime resizable column width decreases to provide that extra 20px. Even tried setforcefit(true).

What I want is if scrollbar is not there, those extra space should not come(can be visible in header bar and if using border of grid).
 Another question here. Is scrollbar property of Grid or contentpanel it is added to? For my case content panel is much bigger than the grid.

Comment: how can grid use full width?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the GXT grid in a container that will resize it. When the grid's content exceeds the height of the vertical layout container, scroll bars would appears in the grid's body.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'  
  xmlns:grid='urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid'       
  xmlns:container="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container">

<ui:with field="layoutData" type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData">
  <ui:attributes width="1" height="1" />
</ui:with>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore" field="store" />

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnModel" field="cm" />

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.GridView" field="view">
  <ui:attributes forceFit="true" autoFill="true" ></ui:attributes>
</ui:with>

<container:VerticalLayoutContainer ui:field="container">
  <container:child layoutData="{layoutData}">
    <grid:Grid store="{store}" cm="{cm}" view="{view}" />
  </container:child>
</container:VerticalLayoutContainer>

</ui:UiBinder>
```